# Next Number with Distinct Digits CCC 2013 Senior 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

The [2013 CCC Senior 1 problem on page 4](https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing/2013/stage1/seniorEn.pdf)  is to find the smallest number that is larger than the input with distinct digits as the title explains.
I'm a total beginner at programming and I can't find what's wrong with this code:

```
year = 1987
distinct = 'no'
a = []
while distinct != 'yes':
    year += 1
    for i in str(year):
        if i not in a:
            a.append(i)
            distinct = "yes"
        else:
            distinct = "no"
            break

print(year)
```

I think the code is still in the while loop but I don't understand why. The code above is supposed to print 2013. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am not clear about what you want. Your statement *The question is to find the smallest number that is larger than the input with distinct digits as the title explains* is totally different from your code

Comment: the input here is 1987 sorry if I wasn't clear on that @MoinuddinQuadri

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri It says so in the question...

Answer (score 2):

Your approach to increment the year by 1 and check if the digits are distinct is correct, and your code is almost correct. Your mistake is that you initialize `a[]`, your set of digits in the year, only once, but it should be initialized to empty for each year. Move the line `a = []` to after the line `year += 1` and give it the proper indentation and your code will work. That would make your code into:

```
year = 1987
distinct = 'no'
while distinct != 'yes':
    year += 1
    a = []
    for i in str(year):
        if i not in a:
            a.append(i)
            distinct = "yes"
        else:
            distinct = "no"
            break

print(year)
```

Another approach is to use a set, which automatically removes any duplicates. You can check if making the string of the year into a set changes its size. So perhaps use this, which also avoids using a status variable like `distinct`:

```
year = 1987
year += 1
while len(set(str(year))) != len(str(year)):
    year += 1
print(year)
```

If you want that status variable, or do not like that repeated line `year += 1`, you could do this:

```
year = 1987
distinct = False
while not distinct:
    year += 1
    if len(set(str(year))) == len(str(year)):
        distinct = True
print(year)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I don't quite understand what you meant by "You can't check each digit in the year and then check if it is in the year". I meant to check i in str(year) against the list a

Comment: @JimmyQi: Oops, I misunderstood something in your code. I have checked it more thoroughly and revised my answer. I hope this helps.