# Find years with distinct digits - CCC 2013

Tags: java, stack

A similar question [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965525/next-number-with-distinct-digits-ccc-2013-senior-1) in Python but I'm using Java and Java doesn't have builtin counting for strings.

(Here's the answer in Python: http://mmhs.ca/ccc/2013/ccc2013j3.txt)

So far I have a scanner package to ask for input, and then I'm using a linkedlist along with a stack to take an "x" amount of digit integer and separate the ints into separate numbers.

Here's where I'm stuck, I have no way to take the output from the `Stack.pop()` and put each individual separated integer into a new variable to do comparison operations in.

I tried doing this with the stack, but hit an error at `digit[i] = stack.pop()` part.

Could someone point me in the right direction here? I could increment each digit by one starting with the ones column but that would slow the code down, and the conditions would take forever to run/use up a lot of memory.

Here's the code:

```
LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<>();
while (yeardigits > 0) {
    stack.push( yeardigits % 10 );
    yeardigits = yeardigits / 10;
}

while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(stack.pop());

    for (int i = 1; i <= digitstot; i++) {
        int keeptrack = 0;
        keeptrack++;
        // digit[i] = stack.pop();
        System.out.println(digit[i]);
        digit[i] = keeptrack;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Set<Integer>` instead ` LinkedList<Integer>`. then just check the size.

Comment: @dehasi - to keep the values of stack.pop in specific integers?

Comment: if I understand you right, you want to check in all digits in a number distinct (i.e. 2013). You split the number to digits, but then put them to a stack. what for? It easier just to put them into a set. And if you don't have repeatable digits in the number, the set size will be exact 4.

Comment: The highest possible number with all distinct digits (in decimal) is `9,876,543,210`. That's tiny in terms of what computers are capable of. I highly doubt any reasonable algorithm you could think of would have memory or speed issues.

Comment: My teacher is grading by compilation speed and memory usage :(  and I'm still stuck at as to how I should go about doing this - if I could use the values returned in the loop within Stack.pop() and assign each looped value to an integer, then life would be great - that's the one part I can't do right now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the linked list. A straight forward solution would be to increase the given number by one and check if the result contains only distinct numbers. If so, then you have found the solution. If no, do the next iteration. This could be implemented like this:

```
public class NumberFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long number = 10L;
        while (number++ <= 9876543210L) {
            if (hasDistinctDigits(String.valueOf(number))) {
                System.out.println("Next number: " + number);
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No bigger number possible");
        return;
    }

    private static boolean hasDistinctDigits(String number) {
        if (number.length() == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        String rest = number.substring(1);
        if (rest.contains(number.substring(0,1))) {
            return false;
        }
        return hasDistinctDigits(rest);
    }
}
```

That solution is quite inefficient, as it potentially loops quite a few times and creates a lot of strings. It still executes in a second or two on any modern computer.

If you are looking for efficiency, then a more advanced algorithm should be used. You could start searching the number for duplicate digits, starting from the highest position in the number to the lowest. If none are found, you are done. If you found one, then increase the digit at that position and set all digits in the lower positions to the lowest possible values. Special care needs to be taken when you increase the digit 9, where you need to increase the digit in the higher position. This is reasonably efficient, as it only does a few main loops (less than 10) an uses a single array to store the digits, but involves a little more code.

```
public class NumberFinder1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long number = 9876543208L;

        if (number > 9876543210L || number < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number to big or too small: " + number);
        }
        MyNumber myNumber = new MyNumber(++number);
        while (true) {
            int highestIndexOfDuplicateDigit = myNumber.getHighestIndexOfDuplicateDigit();
            if (highestIndexOfDuplicateDigit == -1) {
                System.out.println(myNumber.toString());
                return;
            }
            myNumber.increaseDigitAtPosition(highestIndexOfDuplicateDigit);
        }
    }

    private static class MyNumber {
        int[] digits = new int[10];
        int numberOfDigits;

        public MyNumber(long number) {
            while (numberOfDigits < 10 && number > 0) {
                digits[numberOfDigits] = (int) (number % 10);
                number = number / 10;
                numberOfDigits++;
            }
        }

        public int getHighestIndexOfDuplicateDigit() {
            return getHighestIndexOfDuplicateDigit(0, numberOfDigits - 1);
        }

        public int getHighestIndexOfDuplicateDigit(int from, int to) {
            if (from == to) {
                return -1;
            }
            for (int i = to - 1; i >= from; i--) {
                if (digits[to] == digits[i]) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return getHighestIndexOfDuplicateDigit(from, to - 1);
        }

        public void increaseDigitAtPosition(int index) {
            if (digits[index] < 9) {
                digits[index]++;
                for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    digits[i] = index - 1 - i;
                }
            } else {
                increaseDigitAtPosition(++index);
                if (index == numberOfDigits) {
                    numberOfDigits++;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = numberOfDigits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                stringBuilder.append(digits[i]);
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
}
```